# Help with vacuums?

Tags: pressure, vacuum, air, atmospheric-science, volume

Okay, here is my understanding. Please correct me if anything here is incorrect. Suppose I have a cube with a side length of ten inches. It has a surface area of 600 square inches, and at an atmospheric pressure of 14.7 pounds per square inch, we can approximate 8800 pounds of air are applied on the cube by the atmosphere. The cube has a volume of 1000 cubic inches of air. But since there is air on the inside of the cube, and the pressure is equal, there pressure is cancelled out.

Now suppose we were to have a bunch of cubes with ten inch sides. We remove 1/2 of the air from the inside of one, and 1/4 of the air from another, and 1/10 from another. How can we calculate the actual pressure of the atmosphere on the cube?

Comment: You mean "the force" not "the pressure" on the cube, presumably. Net force $F=A \Delta p$

Comment: Can you explain that formula please?

Comment: The net force is the difference in pressure multiplied by the area. So if you take half the air out of the cube but keep the volume and temperature constant, then the pressure inside is half the pressure outside- to the net pressure is half of the total air pressure.